# Execute stored procedure parameter set to any

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, exec

I'm working on a database that has multiple stored procedures created and I need to use them to make some reports but I don't know how because when I try to execute says that the stored procedure needs some input parameters to work

```
exec SomeStoredProcedure @parameter1="I don't know what to put here", @parameter2="same"
```

Like the code above I don't know what to put as an entry in the input of the parameter, is there a way to execute the stored procedure without them? Or put something like ANY or ALL?

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: Oh! sorry I'm working with SQL, is that what you mean?

Comment: it general case it is not possible. Some procedures can have optional parameters with some default values, but in any case the mandatory parameters should be provided

Comment: I understand, will have to try to contact the owners of the database then, thanks!

Comment: If you have access to the database then look up the parameters and their type in SSMS. If you have the correct rights you can even check the code and see what these parameters are good for.

Comment: @KnutBoehnert I think I have permission in this database to look everywhere, but I don't know where can I check the code and see what are the parameters do

Comment: You would look in the stored procedure code. You can get from the object explorer.[YourDatabase] -> Programmability -> Stored Procedures. Right click the one you want to view and click modify. Just be careful because if make changes and hit f5 you just changed the procedure which might break something else.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks! I could find it, I'll be careful